# LibGDX - isKeyPressed() do not count just one

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to do a game. When you press "A" my character was supposed to jump ONE square forward, but he is jumping like 7 squares each time I press the "A" key. Someone knows how to limit it to 1? I know why it is happening, but I didn't find any ways to do that until now.

My "Player" class code, that is my Character class:

```
ArrayList<Square> squareList = new ArrayList<Square>();
int count = 0;
Vector2 position = new Vector2(50,50);
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
{
    j = j + 1;
    position.x = squareList.get(i).getPosition().x;
    position.y = squareList.get(i).getPosition().y;
    i++;

}
```

Comment: position.x = squareList.get(i).getPosition().x;
    position.y = squareList.get(i).getPosition().y;

You should divide that value for slowing down the player.

Comment: The problem is that you are using GDX.isInput.isKeyPressed() instead use Gdx.input.justTouched()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this i imagine would work:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.P)) {
    // Use a helper so that a held-down button does not continuously switch between states with every tick
    if (pauseHelper) {
        if (isPaused) {
            Util.toConsole ("No longer paused");
            isPaused = false;
        }
        else {
            Util.toConsole ("Now paused");
            isPaused = true;
        }
        pauseHelper = false;
    }
}
else {
    pauseHelper = true;
}
```

(See http://pastebin.com/vsVWeHj6)

However, technically you need to implement an [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) provided by LibGDX to handle key presses.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.A)) {
    System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
}
```

It only runs once when you press the key, but if you press and hold it only triggers once. Tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it if you don't want to implement an InputProcessor:

```
//Member variable:
boolean mAKeyWasPressed = false;

//In method:
boolean aKeyIsPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A);
if (aKeyIsPressed && !mAKeyWasPressed)
    //Just pressed. Do stuff here.
}
mAKeyWasPressed = aKeyIsPressed;
```